# Nifi put / append output of FetchHBaseRow back to the flowfile

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a csv file with 10 fields. I need to lookup hbase to get a value corresponding to one of the csv fields. The resultant hbase field should be appended to the csv file. 
Using Nifi, I built the following flow.

> GenerateFlowFile (create a csv record) --> UpdateRecord(configured
>   avro schema name to read incoming csv file) --> ConvertRecord
>   (configured CSV Reader & JSON writer) --> SplitJSON -->
>   EvaluateJSONPath(to fetch the row key for hbase lookup) -->
>   FetchHBaseRow (got the output as a flow-file attribute)

Now, the challenge is  to read the contents of the attribute '`hbase.row`' which is a JSON, pick one of the `field-value` pair, append it to the flow file content

Answer (score 1):

Expression Language has a jsonPath function:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#jsonpath

You should be able to use UpdateAttribute to create a new attribute that contains the extracted field, something like firstName = ${myJson:jsonPath('$.firstName')} would extract the value of firstName into an attribute called firstName, starting from the attribute myJson.

After that you should be able to use UpdateRecord to add the value into the flow file content, assuming your schema has a field for the value.

Comment: Thanks Bran, jsonPath helped me..
Coming to the last part of the question...now that i have a filed from hbase lookup, i want to add it to the incoming flowfile and put it in hdfs. UpdateRecord wont help because, i/p schema has 10 fields...where as, output should have 11
I am using replaceText...

Comment: Why not make a second schema that has 11 fields and in UpdateRecord use one schema as the read schema and the other as the write schema, or just always have 11 fields make the one field nullable so it isn't populated til the end of the flow?